How to determine (possibly mixed radix) bases for which a number's representation is "digit-wise maximal"?
For some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and (possibly mixed radix) basis $B$, let $\mathrm{repr}_B(n) = d_1d_2d_3\ldots d_m$ be the representation of $n$ in basis $B$. Call such a representation digit-wise maximal if for all $x < n$ and $i \in [m]$, $\mathrm{repr}_B(x)_i \leq \mathrm{repr}_B(n)_i$ (that is to say, each "digit" of $n$ is at least as large as the corresponding digit of each number less than it).
For a given number $n$, my goal is to find bases (assuming they exist) such that $n$ is digit-wise maximal. Computational approaches are welcome here as well.
An example of such a number and basis. $n = 101$, $B = [51,17,1]$. $\mathrm{repr}_B(n) = [1,2,16]$.

Well for any $n$, in base $n+1$ the numbers $n\ldots n$  are digitwise maximal.

Every digit (except possibly the leftmost digit) of $\mathrm{repr}_B(n)$ would need to be the largest digit that can appear in that place, wouldn't it?

No, I don't think so. The right-most digit almost certainly has to be the largest digit that can appear in that place, but in the example I gave in the question this is not true of the other digits. The requirement is only on numbers x < n. There can be numbers with the same digit-length as n for which the property doesn't hold.

@DavidK Your observation is right for unmixed base. For mixed base the OP has a more interesting example.

@EthanBolker I wrote "largest digit that can appear in that place". Surely if the place values for base $B$ are $[51,17,1]$ then we cannot have $[0,3,0]$ or any other representation with a $3$ or greater in the $17$s place; so $2$ is the greatest digit that can occur in that place and in $[1,2,16]$ only the leading digit is (possibly) not the largest that can be written in its place.

@DavidK OK. I read too quickly.

In other words, if the last three place values are $51,17,1$ then any digit-wise maximal number of three or more digits must end in $2,16$.

Let $\operatorname{num}_B(d_m,d_{m-1},\ldots,d_3,d_2,d_1)$ be the numeric value of the digit sequence $[d_m,d_{m-1},\ldots,d_3,d_2,d_1]$ in base $B$ provided that the digit sequence is a valid representation.
If the last three place values of $B$ are $51,17,1$ then
$\operatorname{num}_B(2,16)=50$.
In any representation $[\ldots,d_3,d_2,d_1]$ we have $d_2 \leq 2$ and $d_1  \leq 16$,
so no $n \geq 51$ can be digit-wise maximal unless its last two digits are precisely
$2,16$.
In general, suppose the place values of base $B$ are
$\ldots, v_3, v_2, v_1$ where $v_1=1$ and $b_i = v_{i+1}/v_i$ for every $i$.
Then for every digit-wise maximal $n \geq v_{k+1}$,
the last $k$ digits of $n$ in base $B$ are
$$b_k-1, b_{k-1}-1, \ldots, b_3-1, b_2-1, b_1-1.$$
What this implies is that in order for $n$ to be digit-wise maximal in base $B$,
we must have $n = d_i v_i - 1$ and $1 \leq d_i \leq v_{i+1}/v_i - 1$
where $v_{i+1},v_i$ are two consecutive place values of $B$.
For example, if $n+1$ is prime then the last two place values of $B$ must be
$v,1$ where $v \geq n+1$.
More generally, one of the place values of $B$ must divide $n+1$ and the next larger place value must be greater than $n+1$.
Any base $B$ that satisfies these requirements will give a digit-wise maximal representation.
